# How can I bring a terribly old branch up to speed with the main one?

Tags: git

One of our branches hasn't been worked on for 10 months, we want to bring it up to speed with main but there's to many merge conflicts. How can I simply make it be a fork off the current one and discard all conflicts?

Comment: If by "discard all conflicts" you mean removing the branch's changes and having it point to the latest commit in your main branch, you can just reset to the most recent commit (after checking out the old branch): `git reset --hard branch_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with discarding any changes on branch foo, just do:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout foo
git reset --hard origin/foo
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding to that I also had to do a forced push to make github accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume rebasing won't be possible if it's 10 months old, because you've probably gone through a lot of pushes and pulls between different developer repositories now?

It sounds like if you have too many fundamental code differences, someone is just going to have to suck it up and manually do the merge work, at least GIT should be pointing out all the work to be done here.

Failing that, you can always just rewrite the features you need from the old branch into the latest codebase, I suppose? As annoying as it is, it's usually a pretty fast to recreate something you already made.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are saying that you just want all the merge conflicts to disappear so that you can commit the results of the merge.  If so, just do a 'git rm' of all the files that show up as 'need merge / conflict'.  After that you can commit the 'old branch'.  Then, from the new code base, copy over each of the files that you deleted with the 'git rm', add them, and commit again.  Now you've got 1) all the new code, 2) most of the old code and 3) work ahead to get it working.

Comment: This is bad advice. It just defers the work of resolving API changes and conflicts until later, except that now you no longer have git telling you what is in conflict.

Comment: Give me a break.  It is not my workflow and I prefaced the comment with 'it sounds like'.  The guy might be a git noob who knows the conflicts don't matter but doesn't know how to resolve them.  And I added 'work ahead to get it working' to stress that things weren't going to work.  Importantly, I provided an actual answer to is problem.  He said 'discard all conflicts', did he not.  Why are you dinging me?

Comment: Because a correct answer would tell him the solution to the bigger picture problem, pointing out how this approach will end up being more work than just doing it the hard way now.